# Why have a separate call to get Json?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to get some Json to the client side from the server and it's somewhat troublesome as almost all tutorials assume an Ajax call to a separate action to get the Json.

This led me to think that there must be some reason why it is done this way. In Asp.Net MVC we can pass a Model along with the view to get the information but we can't seem to easily pass a Json object. Instead you are supposed to make a separate call to get this information.

What if the Json info is known when the page is generated, why not generate it at the same time?

---

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. While it's nice to hear of ways to get Json to the client, the question is actually whether there is a specific reason the Ajax call method is much more popular, like security or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put something like this into your view? (rough pseudo code, assuming using a Razor view)

`< script >`

var myJSON = { Field: @model.Field, Field2: @model.Field2 };

< /script >

Comment: I can up to a point. Having a collection and having to add multiple childobjects and even inserting it into Knockoutjs Observables I find it to be too much code for a cshtml page. Also my questions is more about why do it one way and not the other. It still seems to be the simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not need both at the same time... on the first call will be to get html (the view of the data - represented by a view model), and any ajax calls will be to get the possibly updated data (json serialized view model).

Comment: I would think that that would only be in specific cases you might wan't to get the data separably but here it's assumed in almost all cases.

Answer (score 1):

No reason why you can't. You could use the javacript serializer to create a JSON string that drop on the page. You could also create an action that return the json string that you called from a script tag.

What you want if you're using KnockOut, would be the Mapping plugin that turns an ordinary JS object, like that generated above, into an observable ready for KnockOut to use. See here from info. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [content-negotiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) by setting accept header. This is considered a best practice (and according to some RESTful).

This needs to be supported and implemented at server as well. ASP NET MVC **does not make it easy** to support content-negotiation and you have to implement it yourself by if-else or using ActionFilter and implementing action selector.